# ImportError: cannot import name 'weak_script_method'

Tags: pytorch

When I use PyTorch to import weak_script_method, the code throws an error:

> from torch._jit_internal import weak_script_method ImportError: cannot
>   import name 'weak_script_method'

The code is:

```
from torch._jit_internal import weak_script_method
```

Does anyone have an idea about this? How to fix this error?

Comment: Do you get the error even if you remove the first 4 lines?

Comment: removed, the error still shows up

Comment: Great! That means you can remove them from the question as they are not relevant.

Comment: Great!~~~ I removed them from the question. But do you have any other ideas about this error??

Comment: Well, since it's only one line it is probably your installation that is causing the error. I suspect that maybe you're using a version of `torch` that doesn't have `weak_script_method`. What is you torch version? (`print(torch.__version__)`)

Comment: torch version is 1.2.0

Comment: Could I possibly know if the torch of this version has weak_script_method or not?

Answer (score 0):

`weak_script_method` is in `_jit_internal.py` in version `v1.1.0`

As you can look up here:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v1.1.0/torch/_jit_internal.py

In version `v1.2.0` is is no longer there:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v1.1.0/torch/_jit_internal.py

by inspecting the history you can find this commit which has removed the function you want:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/commit/10c4b98ade8349d841518d22f19a653a939e260c#diff-ee07db084d958260fd24b4b02d4f078d

I've never needed `weak_script_method` myself and I don't know what you need it for. It seems the pytorch developers don't need it any longer...
Best of luck!

Comment: I change the PyTorch version back to 1.0.0 and it works. Thank you so much.